# Proof that MAX-2-SAT is NP-hard

Tags: np-hard, satisfiability, 2-sat

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-satisfiability#Maximum-2-satisfiability), while the 2SAT problem is polynomial, its maximization variant MAX2SAT is NP-hard. But, they do not provide a reference for this claim. Is this obvious? If not, where can I find the reduction used to prove this claim?

Comment: Try formulating independent set problem as a max 2SAT problem.

Comment: Thanks! I found the original proof here: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397576900591 in pages 4-6.